# How to implement the dependencies injection with lazy loading by native TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, lazy-loading

The frameworks developers likes to brag by implementation of **Dependencies Injection** concept.
Below implementation is native, simple and type-safe.

```js
// All below gateways and services are the abstractions
type ApplicationDependencies = Readonly<{
  gateways: Readonly<{
    category: CategoryGateway;
    product: ProductGateway;
  }>;
  services: Readonly<{
    authentication: AuthenticationService;
  }>;
}>;


export default abstract class DependenciesInjector {

  private static dependencies: ApplicationDependencies | null = null;

  public static setDependencies(dependencies: ApplicationDependencies): void {
    DependenciesInjector.dependencies = dependencies;
  }

  private static getDependencies(): ApplicationDependencies {

    if (DependenciesInjector.dependencies === null) {
      throw new Error("The DependenciesInjector has not been initialized");
    }


    return DependenciesInjector.dependencies;
  }


  public static get gateways(): ApplicationDependencies["gateways"] {
    return DependenciesInjector.getDependencies().gateways;
  }

  public static get services(): ApplicationDependencies["services"] {
    return DependenciesInjector.getDependencies().services;
  }
}
```

The initializing must be executed in the entry point:

```js
ApplicationDependencies.setDependencies({
  gateways: {
    category: new CategoryAxiosGateway(),
    product: new ProductAxiosGateway()
  },
  services: {
    authentication: new AuthenticationCognitoService()
  }
});
```

Now these dependencies could be injected as

```js
import { Vue as VueComponent, Options as VueComponentConfiguration } from "vue-property-decorator";

@VueComponentConfiguration({})
export default class CategoriesManager extends VueComponent {
  
  private readonly categoryGateway!: CategoryGateway;

  // It's O'K from the viewpoint of TypeScript, but this way `categoryGateway` will become to
  //    reactive field (Vue's 'data') which could be undesirably
  // private readonly categoryGateway!: CategoryGateway = DependenciesInjector.gateways.category;

  public created(): void {
    this.categoryGateway = DependenciesInjector.gateways.category;
  }
}
```

Above approach is enough good for most console and server applications but non-optimal for the fronted applications. It could be a tens of dependencies, and all of them will be immediately initialized once any page of the application will be accessed.

How to solve it? The conceptual answer is "the manipulations with modules dynamic loading" AKA "lazy loading". What I want to ask is could it be implemented without changing of injection method (as demonstrated on above Vue component) and if yes - how?.

### The examples of existing implementations

#### Vue-router

> Vue Router supports dynamic imports out of the box, meaning you can
> replace static imports with dynamic ones:
>
> ````js
> import('./views/UserDetails.vue')
>
> const router = createRouter({   // ...   routes: [{ path:
> '/users/:id', component: UserDetails }], }) ```
> ````
>
> [vue-router
> documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

Herewith, the accessing to components does not change.

#### NestJS

> To load modules on-demand, Nest provides the LazyModuleLoader class
> that can be injected into a class in the normal way:
>
> ```js
> constructor(private lazyModuleLoader: LazyModuleLoader) {} }
> ```
>
> [NestJS
> documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lazy-loading-modules)

### The way of thinking about my case

We can not set dependencies by the same way as previous.
It will be something like

```js
ApplicationDependencies.setDependencies({
  gateways: {
    category: async (): Promise<CategoryGateway> => import("@Data/Gateways/CategoryAxiosGateway"),
    product: async (): Promise<ProductGateway> => import("@Data/Gateways/ProductAxiosGateway")
  },
  services: {
    authentication: async (): Promise<AuthenticationService> => import ("@Services/Gateways/ProductAxiosGateway")
  }
});
```

Well, it is just the draft. We need to deal with correct typings, default/non-default imports etc.
We need to rewrite the **DependenciesInjector** and **ApplicationDependencies** also. But how to access these dependencies?

```js
@VueComponentConfiguration({})
export default class CategoriesManager extends VueComponent {
  
  private readonly categoryGateway!: CategoryGateway;

  public async created(): void {
    this.categoryGateway = await DependenciesInjector.gateways.category;
  }
}
```

I was need make the `crated` method async.
Could I implement the lazy loading such as keep the above Vue component as it was in the previous example? If no, which the best implementation is possible?

Please note that answer to this topics requires the explanation of the concept, but not the recommendation of the third-partly solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, so I wrote DI lib for that. Works like a charm. Very productive for me and my team.

It is called [`iti`](https://github.com/molszanski/iti) and it has some nice React bindings, so it should be possible to port them to Vue.

Basically it works like this:
[image]

You can also check the React example on the docs:

https://itijs.org/docs/with-react/react-full#async-request-for-single-item-in-iti

```js
  import { createContainer } from "iti"

  // blue.ts
  // export class Blue implements IColor {}
  // rainbow-service.ts
  // export class RainbowSegment { constructor(c: IColor) {} }

  // async imports, no trace in runtime
  export const container = createContainer()
    .add(() => ({
      blue: async () => {
        const { Blue } = await import("./blue")
        return new Blue()
      },
    }))
    .add((ctx) => ({
      blueRainbowSegment: async () => {
        const { RainbowSegment } = await import("./rainbow-service")
        return new RainbowSegment(ctx.blue)
      },
    }))

  const blueSegment = await container.items.blueRainbowSegment
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but the answer to this topics requires the explanation of the concept, but not the recommendation of the third-partly solution. Would you please to explain how you have solved above problem in your library?

Comment: Sure! I would love to explain. What part needs explaining?

Comment: Thank you for the support of your answer. First: is you solution TypeScript-save? Does TypeScript know the type of `container.items.blueRainbowSegment` and any other properties of `items`?

Comment: Yes, it is 100% automatically type safe :) You can try it in playground
https://itijs.org/docs/playground/

Comment: O'K thank you! I have checked your library. I understand that you want a lot of people use your library, but let me repeat that this question was about DIY solution. I'll upvote your question for the your efforts and the support and add my DIY answer.

Comment: I am just trying to answer your question and show the working solution and an API. You can recreate it manually for the most part without any problem

Answer (score 0):

Below example includes one static dependency (**CategoryGateway**) and one asynchronous dependency (**ProductGateway**). Both are the interfaces, developing the **ClientDependenciesInjector** class we does not know at advance how it will be implemented.

```js
/* --- Application business rules ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
import type CategoryGateway from "@Gateways/CategoryGateway";
import type ProductGateway from "@Gateways/ProductGateway";

/* --- Utils -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
import {
  Logger,
  ClassRedundantSubsequentInitializationError,
  ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError,
  isNull,
  isNotNull
} from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";


class ClientDependenciesInjector {

  private static selfSoleInstance: ClientDependenciesInjector | null = null;


  private readonly categoryGateway: CategoryGateway;

  private productGateway: ProductGateway | null = null;
  private readonly productGatewayClassLoader: ClientDependenciesInjector.ImplementationLoader<ProductGateway>;


  public static initialize(dependencies: ClientDependenciesInjector.DependenciesInitialization): void {

    if (isNotNull(ClientDependenciesInjector.selfSoleInstance)) {
      Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
        errorInstance: new ClassRedundantSubsequentInitializationError({ className: "ClientDependenciesInjector" }),
        title: ClassRedundantSubsequentInitializationError.localization.defaultTitle,
        occurrenceLocation: "ClientDependenciesInjector.initialize(dependencies)"
      });
    }


    ClientDependenciesInjector.selfSoleInstance = new ClientDependenciesInjector(dependencies);

  }


  private constructor(dependencies: ClientDependenciesInjector.DependenciesInitialization) {
    this.categoryGateway = dependencies.gateways.category;
    this.productGatewayClassLoader = dependencies.gateways.product;
  }


  public static get categoryGateway(): CategoryGateway {
    return ClientDependenciesInjector.getExpectedHasBeenInitializedSelfSoleInstance().categoryGateway;
  }

  public static async loadProductGateway(): Promise<ProductGateway> {

    const selfInstance: ClientDependenciesInjector = ClientDependenciesInjector.
        getExpectedHasBeenInitializedSelfSoleInstance();

    if (isNull(selfInstance.productGateway)) {
      selfInstance.productGateway = new (await selfInstance.productGatewayClassLoader())();
    }

    return selfInstance.productGateway;

  }


  private static getExpectedHasBeenInitializedSelfSoleInstance(): ClientDependenciesInjector {

    if (isNull(ClientDependenciesInjector.selfSoleInstance)) {
      Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
        errorInstance: new ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError({
          className: "ExperimentalDependenciesInjector",
          initializingMethodName: "initialize"
        }),
        title: ClassRequiredInitializationHasNotBeenExecutedError.localization.defaultTitle,
        occurrenceLocation: "ClientDependenciesInjector.getExpectedHasBeenInitializedSelfSoleInstance()"
      });
    }


    return ClientDependenciesInjector.selfSoleInstance;

  }

}


namespace ClientDependenciesInjector {

  export type DependenciesInitialization = Readonly<{
    gateways: Readonly<{
      category: CategoryGateway;
      product: ImplementationLoader<ProductGateway>;
  }>;

  export type AsynchronousImplementation<Abstraction> = Promise<new () => Abstraction>;
  export type ImplementationLoader<Abstraction> = () => AsynchronousImplementation<Abstraction>;

}


export default ClientDependenciesInjector;
```

In the **ProductGateway** case, instead of static dependency we are accepting the asynchronous loader (see example below how to pass it during initialization). Then, this loading will be invoked once on demand and loaded dependency will be cached to the `productGateway` field.

Now it may be used as:

```js
/* --- Application business rules --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
import type ProductGateway from "@Gateways/ProductGateway";

/* --- Data --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
import CategoryMockGateway from "@MockDataSource/Gateways/CategoryMockGateway";


/* --- Utils -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
import ClientDependenciesInjector from "@Client/ClientDependenciesInjector";


(function executeApplication(): void {

  ClientDependenciesInjector.initialize({
    gateways: {
      category: new CategoryMockGateway(),
      product: async (): ClientDependenciesInjector.AsynchronousImplementation<ProductGateway> =>
          (await import("@MockDataSource/Gateways/ProductMockGateway")).default
    }
  });

})();
```

### Maybe could be improved

For each asynchronous dependency like `productGateway` the separate method as `loadProductGateway` is required. Maybe there is some way to simplify it without breaking of the type safety...

Waiting for the constructive criticism ^_~